# What's the point of variables in C# 7.0's pattern matching?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I've been reading about the "is" operator pattern matching in C# 7.0 and I don't see the reason for variable declaration.

If we have this

```
if(str is string s)
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

What's the point of "s"?

In [this post](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/152/c-sharp-7-is-operator-patterns-you-wont-need-as-as-often) it says the whole point of such variables is not to access the evaluated object twice. But there's no point!

If this is `true` then that means `str` is just a string object and accessing it twice to `Console.WriteLine` it shouldn't be that much of a consideration. In any case it's content is copied to `s` accessing which surely would take just as much time as `str`.

What I am asking is - why declare variables in the pattern matching feature of C#7.0 when accessing the evaluated variable should be about the same operation as copying it and then accessing it's copy?

Comment: you are missing the point that "str" is being casted to string, not copied. In this example it may not seem important but what if you wanted to access a specific property on a string ?

Comment: Also the variable is optional, so you can still just use `str is string` if you are not interested in the variable

Comment: @SelmanGenç, I thought "o is string" would only be true if "o" is a string. Do you mean it will return true if o can be safely cast to a string, instead?

Comment: @J.Doe It'll be true if the runtime type of the *value* in `str`is `string`. The compile time type of `str` could be `object`. The `is` operator essentially tries to do a cast and returns true if the cast would succeed. The variable declaration allows you to simultaneously capture the result of the cast in a new variable so that you can use it as the specified type.

Comment: This example is an unfortunate one, because you could call `Console.WriteLine(str)` anyway. But try with `if (str is string s) { Console.WriteLine(s.Length);` for example. Note that the content of the string isn't copied - just the reference, with a type of `string` (instead of `object`, which I assume is the declared type of `str`).

Comment: @DaisyShipton, Oh, I get it, now! :) Thanks! If you post that as an answer - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the point of "s"?

It's a variable of the type that you've just checked for, which you often want to use.

Your example is an unfortunate one as `Console.WriteLine` accepts `object` as well... but suppose you wanted to print out the length of the string. Here's a complete example *without* pattern matching:

```
public void PrintLengthIfString(object obj)
{
    if (obj is string)
    {
        string str = (string) obj;
        Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
    }
}
```

It's not only longer, but it's performing the same check twice, effectively: once for the `is` operator, and once for the cast. Pattern matching make this simpler, by getting the value of the string as part of the `is` operator:

```
public void PrintLengthIfString(object obj)
{
    if (obj is string str)
    {
        // No cast here, it's in the pattern match!
        Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
    }
}
```